# is there any cms applications with spring and hibernate and jsp

Tags: content-management-system

Hi I Want to know about the existing cms applications using the spring and hibernate and jsp kindly help me to download the applications

please help me to download the application

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) allows you to build your own CMS in pretty short order.  Would that work for you?